# Assert multiple values in an XML response received on querying DB in SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to retrieve some data from db and based on the response, I have to pass or fail a test case. I have to do this each time I query the db

I am able to make the connection to the db and get the response. However, not quite sure on how to assert the values from the response

Tried to use Script Assertion but not able to figure out as I am completely new at this

```
<Results>
<ResultSet fetchSize="10">
    <Row rowNumber="1">
        <T1>TEXT1</T1>
        <T2>TASK1</T2>
        <T3>Value1</T3>
        <T4>xyz</T4>
      </Row>
       <Row rowNumber="2">
        <T1>TEXT2</T1>
        <T2>TASK2</T2>
        <T3>Value1</T3>
        <T4>ABC</T4>
      </Row>
     </ResultSet>
```

From the above response, on the first step I will have to assert that "TASK1" exists and the "Value1" exists with in the same set followed by the "TASK2" and "Value1"

Please let me know if this is vague so that I can try to modify my query

Comment: Surya, have you got chance to look at the solution provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Script Assertion](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) for the JDBC Request test step in soapUI.

**Script assertion**

```
//define your expected data as map. You may add more key value pairs if more Rows
def expectedData = ['TASK1':'Value1', 'TASK2':'Value1']

//Assert if the response is not null
assert context.response, 'Response is not null or empty'

//Parse and get rows
def rows = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.esponse).ResultSet.Row

def getRowData = { data, elementName, elementValue ->
    data.'**'.findAll { it.name() == elementName && it == elementValue }*.parent()
}

def assertionErrors = new StringBuffer()

//Loop thur expectedData and capture the errors
expectedData.each { key, value->
    def matchingRow = getRowData(rows, 'T2', key)[0]
    value == matchingRow.T3.text() ?: assertionErrors.append("Assertion failed for rowNumber ${matchingRow.@rowNumber}\n")
}

//Check and show the result
if (assertionErrors) {
    throw new Error(assertionErrors.toString())
} else {
    log.info 'Assertions passed'
}
```

You may quickly try the solution online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5068433729257472)</kbd>; it shows how failure error message look like.

Note that, column names `T2`, `T3`are used in above script. If the names are different in original result, just make the change at your end.

Also note that `assertion` is not used **deliberately** *to catch all the comparison issues*, do not want to stop at first compare issue.

Comment: Wow!!  I never knew we could do something as such. I have written a lengthy groovy script to assert the values and continue based on the values. From the look of it, I feel I can include it into my existing groovy script. I will try this and let you know if this works :)

Comment: @Surya, not sure you did not seem to check after posting the question. Glad you came back and look for the solution. Mostly assertions can be used in Script Assertion for the same jdbc step instead of separate groovy script (one less test step)

Answer (score 1):

**Use Xpath assertion instead**
**Assertion 1**
/Results/ResultSet[@fetchSize="10"]/Row[1]/T1
**Expected result**
Task1
**Assertion 2**
/Results/ResultSet[@fetchSize="10"]/Row[1]/T3
**Expected result**
Value1

You can add as many Xpath Assertion as you want for any number of nodes.

**Quick Tip:** To generate XPaths use online tools or Oxygen XML Editor. :)

Comment: Thanks bro .. I tried this already. However, as there are so many tasks based on the kind of scenario I test , it was difficult for me to do for each of the Task. Hence I have included a groovy script which will capture the response and based on the values proceed with the further steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try XmlSlurper: http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

To check TASK1:

```
def results = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)

def row1 = results.ResultSet.find { node->
    node.name() == 'Row' && node.@rowNumber == '1'
}

assert row1.T2 == 'TASK1'
```

I hope you'll be able to do the rest by your own ;)

Comment: Thanks Anton. I will include this in my scripts and try